# Streaming video from server in iphone?

Tags: ios, media-player

i wanted to know of i use MediaPlayer framework to stream a live video does it wait till the video is downloaded and it starts playing or it does it simultaneously?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this One :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strSelectedVideoUrl]];
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 400);
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

    [player play];
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player1 = [aNotification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player1];

    [player1.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player1 release];
    player1 = nil;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```